# Different URL required when hosting a WCF service on Windows 7

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-7

I have a WCF service defined as follows:

```xml
<service name="MyService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/ServiceContainer" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="Service" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService" />
</service>
```

My service implements the following contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "DoWork")]
    void MyMethod();
}
```

I host the WCF service as a Windows Service, using `WebServiceHost`.

Hosting on **XP** I call the operation on this URI:

`http://myhost:8080/ServiceContainer/DoWork`

*(i.e. base address / URI template)*

Hosting on **Windows 7**, the same URI fails (with a `404` error). However, the following URI succeeds:

`http://myhost:8080/ServiceContainer/Service/DoWork`

*(i.e. base address / **endpoint address** / URI template)*

The second URI also works on XP. The OS of the client calling the service makes no difference.

What is the reason for this difference in behaviour between the two operating systems? Is the `UriTemplate` more restrictive under Windows 7 perhaps? And is all this documented somewhere?

---

**Edit:** I also have the Windows Firewall and an anti-virus scanner running (which I cannot disable). However, I do not see anything in their logs (e.g. `pfirewall.log`) to suggest that something is being blocked.

**Edit 2:** Adding the following reserved URI allowed the Service to be used on Windows 7, but did not affect the above behaviour:

```
netsh http add http://+:8080/ user=\Everyone
```

Comment: In your netsh line you have typed "+:8000" instead of "+:8080".

Comment: The main difference between XP and Win7 should be really the needed registration of the port by "netsh http". Are you sure, you are using the same .NET version in both? Maybe a change in WCF. In fact, "Service/DoWork" sounds more correct to me, after you have specified the endpoint. But I am not an expert here, unfortunately.

Comment: @Philm Thanks, I corrected the port number. I'll check the .NET version. I agree, the Win7 behaviour seems correct, and more secure. Perhaps a bug fix between versions?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a firewall or anti-virus on your system turn it off and check it,404 error is very general.

check with this URL

```
http://myhost:80/ServiceContainer/DoWork
```